# There are lots of "Core i" CPUs, but Dell only offers a few -- who builds systems with the others?

Tags: performance, oem

Passmark shows many varieties of Core i3, i5, and i7 CPUs. Some of them, even at similar prices, are much faster than others.

However Dell only offers a few options, and they're not the fast ones.

For example, Dell offers the Core i5 650 ([benchmark](http://www.cpubenchmark.net/cpu.php?cpu=Intel+Core+i5+650+@+3.20GHz)), which costs $220, and doesn't come close to the performance of the Core i3-2100 ([benchmark](http://www.cpubenchmark.net/cpu.php?cpu=Intel+Core+i3-2100+@+3.10GHz)), which costs $120.

Does anyone sell systems with the faster, cheaper chips?

Comment: Shopping and product recommendations are off topic on SuperUser.

Comment: What @DanielBeck said.  You should also be aware that ix-2xxx series processors are BRAND NEW hence not many people selling them.

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?tbs=shop%3A1&q=intel+core+i3-2100+computers

Answer (score 0):

There will be somebody out there offering them. There are more PC makers than we would ever be able to list.

Of course, if you want a specific combination you can go the Do-It-Yourself route.

Motherboards from large makers are readily available, as are the processors, memory, cases, power supplies, etc.

Whilst gamers often do this, it is frequently also one of the cheapest methods of getting exactly what you want.